# HTML5 video works in Firefox but not IE

Tags: jquery, video, html, html5-video

The HTML5 video player (JW Player) on this page works fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, but not IE: http://bit.ly/9mR6Wy

If you scroll through the carousel component, you'll notice the video's width gets "crushed" on IE and the text next to it, visible on the other browsers, isn't displayed. The video slides are 1 and 5 in the carousel component.

What am I doing wrong? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: well, which version of IE are you testing on ?

Comment: Does this really surprise you?!

Comment: This is with IE9 Beta and 7+8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Video JS](http://videojs.com/) is a video javascript library that seems to work on all major browsers including IE (HTML5 in IE9, fallback to Flash in IE6-8).  They have a demo on the site you can test out.

I'd also recommend looking at the [Dive Into HTML5 Video article](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/video.html).  It has a technical description of the challenges of using the new  tag and discusses methods to make it work cross-browser.  These techniques are what is being used by Video JS and other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer doesn't support HTML5 video. Some form of HTML5 video may make it into IE9, but until then you're out of luck.

Comment: IE9 Beta supports the HTML5 <video> tag w/ H.264.

Answer (score 1):

Try with IE9 beta.

Comment: That's the main one I've used. The JW Player library is supposed to auto-detect and show Flash for non-HTML5 browsers.